# Show that $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:y>x^2\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the usual metric.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to prove that  $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:y>x^2\}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:y-x^2>0\}$. We then want to see that there exists $r>0$ such that $B((x_{0}, y_{0}); r) \subseteq \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2}:y>x^2\}$.

let $(a, b)\in B((x_{0}, y_{0}); r)$ then $\sqrt{ (a-x_{0})^2+(b-y_{0})^2} <r$ Someone told me it might work to take $r=\frac{1}{n}(y_{0}-x_{0}^2)$ Where clearly $r>0$, should really prove that $b>a^{2}$.

But I don't see it really clear, any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to show that a set of the form $$A = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : f(x)>0\}$$ is open, is to show that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, since then $A = f^{-1}( (0,\infty))$, i.e. $A$ is the pre-image of an open set under a continuous function, and thus (by the topological characterization of continuity) again open.

In your case, $f(x,y) = y-x^2$ clearly is continuous.

Comment: I fully approve, but I was really hoping to solve the problem using what I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

We can find appropriate radius using convexity of the set $A =\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid y > x^2\}$.

Take a point $P(x_0,y_0)\in A$. Let's assume WLOG that $x_0 \geq 0$ (not a loss of generality due to symmetry) and let $x_1>0$ such that $y_0 = x_1^2$, which exists since $y_0 > x_0^2 \geq 0$. This is just so that formulas look bit nicer. Take points $A(x_0,x_0^2)$ and $B(x_1,x_1^2)$ on the parabola $y = x^2$. Here's a picture:

[image]

The idea is that due to the convexity of the set $A$, line segment $\overline{AB}$ lies inside $A$ (excluding the endpoints). What we want now is to calculate distance $d(P,AB)$ and this will be our radius $r$.

First, let us find equation of the line $AB$. Since you know coordinates of $A$ and $B$, this is easy. You can see that the equation simplifies to $$y - (x_0+x_1)x+x_0x_1 = 0.$$ We can also argue a posteriori that the system $$y - (x_0+x_1)x+x_0x_1 = 0\\ y = x^2$$ has two solutions for which $x = x_0,x_1$ due to Vieta's formulas, so that line really is intersecting our parabola at points $A$ and $B$.

Finally, we can use formula for distance of a point from a line to get
$$ r = d(P,AB) = \frac{|x_1^2-x_0^2|}{\sqrt{(x_0+x_1)^2+1}} = \frac{y_0-x_0^2}{\sqrt{(|x_0|+\sqrt{y_0})^2+1}}.$$

I will leave it as an exercise for you to verify that the open ball $B(P,r)$ lies in the shaded area and that the shaded area lies inside $A$ due to convexity.

Note that the last formula works for any $x_0$, not just $x_0\geq 0$. As a matter of fact, the whole argument works just the same as long as $x_0$ and $x_1$ are of the same sign.

Comment: Alternatively, you can take a square centered at $P$ with sides parallel to axes whose one vertex lies on the parabola and inscribe a circle in it. I don't know if it's computationally more approachable, but the argument should be clear geometrically.